# SelectionTracker.Builder isn't working IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement recyclerView multi-selection but I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on `StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()`

here is my code

```
tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>("selection1"
                , recyclerView
                , new StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView)
                , new MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView)
                , StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
                .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.<Long>createSelectAnything())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call `recyclerView.setAdapter(...)` before `SelectionTracker.Builder<>(...).build()`

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because at this point the adapter of the RecyclerView has not been set.